# How to match if text contain the same char only n times

Tags: regex

I'm making an API for my website and know i want to create a file load API
 and i want my path regex to only match this pattern

```
"/load/ js or css /filename"
```

i was able to do it with this regex

```
\/load\/(js|css)\/(.+)
```

but the problem is the regex match this as well

```
"/load/js/filename/anythingelse"
```

I don't want any `/` after the file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `.` matches all characters, you need something more specific. For example, if you want anything except `/`, use character groups with exclusion, i.e. `[^<chars-to-exclude>]`:

```
\/load\/(js|css)\/([^/]+)
```

> I don't want to get the file name if there is any `/` after it i don't want the regex to match at all

Add `$` at the end to prevent matches other than at the end of the string:

```
\/load\/(js|css)\/([^/]+)$
```

For completeness, if you are looking for full-string matches, add `^` anchor at the beginning of your regex:

```
^\/load\/(js|css)\/([^/]+)$
```

Comment: sorry i was not specific i don't want to get the file name if there is any / after it i don't want the regex to match at all so i can move to another API route

Comment: @ForKoding: depending on how you are using your regex (full match vs search), you might need to add `^` and `$` to make this work

Comment: I use express js so i really don't know either its doing a match or a search

Comment: Thank you very much i will choose your answer in two minutes